# Is it possible to reverse engineer Scala JVM byte code back into Scala code?

Tags: scala, compilation, jvm, reverse-engineering, decompiling

currentlyI know that you can reverse engineer a Java JVM bytecode back into a Java source code. Is the same procedure is possible in reverse engineering a JVM byte code generated from Scala back to Scala source code?

Thanks,

Boris

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you know the exact Scala version that compiled the code. But that's some tedious work.

Comment: A hint for searching is that this process is usually called **decompiling** as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler and